# Twitter rest api and simplexml_load_file() function issues

Tags: php, rest, twitter, simplexml

I am working  about XML issues in my twitter application project. I want to get user's that use and allow my application tweets and dates.Then I'm trying to write these data into random xml file.Writing xml is good.But I can't read datas from XML file. For that, I've used `simplexml_load_file()` function. But I'm getting Warning:

```
simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: ntcrol.xml:2: parser error : xmlParseEntityRef: no name error and other character errors.How can I solve this problem? My codes are [here][1]
```

Comment: Have you validated your XML output?

Comment: What did you mean about validate XML output ? I think, I've not validate.How can I do?

Comment: Take the XML output and validate it through http://validator.w3.org/